# Linking values in an array to a checkbox C#

Tags: c#, sql, arrays, winforms

I'm looking into how I would be able to display an array of a user's friends but then allow them to pick one or more from the array to send a message to. I figured the best was to do this would be to add checkboxes by each name.

My question is how would I:

1. Add the individual checkboxes
2. More importantly how could it be coded so that when a checkbox is clicked the program knows what users have been selected

```
string friends = "";
        for (int i = 0; i<temp.Count; i++)
        {
            SqlCommand cmdnew = new SqlCommand("SELECT [username] FROM [Table] WHERE userId = '" + temp[i] + "'");
            cmdnew.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cmdnew.Connection = sqlCon;

            SqlDataReader readernew = cmdnew.ExecuteReader();
            while(readernew.Read())
            {
                friends += readernew["username"].ToString();
                friends += "\n";
            }

        }
```

My current code will display the users friends to them.

Comment: Please review your tags. C# and  VBA?  You post SQL C# but ask about checkboxes and forms?  What technology are u using? Wpf? Winforms? Asp.Net (prob. not)?  And why checkboxes? If he has 1000 friends your screen is not big enough. DropDown + Multiselect probably better?

Comment: How would I go about doing a DropDown and Multiselect?

Comment: I'm using windows forms

Comment: Start by editing your question and fixing your tags to adress ppl that are familiar with whatever you use. use Winforms - not Forms. Then store the friends in a suitable datastructure - maybe a list of friends - friends being a class you code.

Comment: I don't see any code for the display of the data. Have you considered using a checked listbox?